# Temperature of water decreasing during boil

Tags: materials, thermodynamics, liquid

I am trying to understand this phenomenon that I have noticed with my system (40L capacity boiler with a NTC thermistor located at the bottom).

When boiling 10 Litres, the temperature reading reaches around 100C when a physical boil is noticed. Then overtime the temperature reading drops to 98-97 C.

However when boiling a capacity of 30-40L the temperature is steady throughout the 60min boil.

What could this to happen? Is this something related to a thermistor (if so why does this only happen with lower capacity). Or is it something else?

Additional Info:

1. System is 3000W electric boiler
2. Thermistor is a type of NTC
3. Testing is done under 20-25 C ambient temperature
4. Testing is done at sea level (No elevation).
5. Thermistor/NTC probe is submerged in liquid at all times.

Comment: *However when boiling a capacity of 30-40L the temperature is steady throughout the 60min boil.* Steady at 100°C I assume, but can you confirm?

Comment: what is the shape and size of the boiler? ... it may be related to the weight of the additional water ... it may also be related to the thermal mass of the water

Comment: How deep is the terminator submerged?

Comment: Your issue is likely a problem with mathematics and your sensors. Ntc‘s arn‘t linear across their entire temperature range…could you post your Algorithm and your specific ntc sensor?